# How to change the output of an AJAX API call from a string into a useable array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, parsing

I have two functions, one function pushes a string to the document area and the other ajax calls chats from the server. When combined it puts the chats into the user facing document. However, it puts all server chats into one bullet as a comma separated string.

My assumption is that I need to create a backend function to split the comma separated strings into an array and then loop through the array to push them into the document individually. My question is, how can I make the output of...

```
Chat.fetch(Chat.display);
```

...into a javascript array that I can then manipulate as stated above.

So far I have attempted declaring a new variable using the .split(',') method and it returns the error

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
```

The same error occurs whenever I try to apply any other method.

The two functions being used are below:

```
//Send msg to document

 function Chat.display(msg){
    $('.messages').prepend('<li>' + msg + '</li>');
  }


//AJAX GET From Server, grabs chats from server

      function Chat.fetch(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
        }).done({
          function(chatStr){
            $('.messages').prepend('chatStr');
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: what does chatStr equal then?  also, you don't neeed to put it in quotes when you prepend it since its a var

Comment: Currently the output of chaining both functions is the output of chatStr. In other words, chatStr equals the chat strings currently stored in the server.

Comment: The Chat.fetch function downloads the most recent messages from the server. Note that it is asynchronous in nature, so it doesn't return anything. Instead, it accepts the Chat.display function as its only argument. 
The result is a comma separated string.